# Reading 2000 files and building hashes in perl

Tags: perl, memory-management

I have a code to parse 2000 csv files and build hashes based on them.
code is running good and fast until it reads ~100 files and there after it is running at snail pace

Memory consumed is ~ 1.8 GB uncompressed
Goal is to build global hash %_hist from the csv files.

File sizes range between 20KB to 30 MB
OS is Mac with 12 GB RAM 
64 bit perl 5.18

I have create every variable in the functions as "my" expecting it to be released after the function exits.
The only persistent global variable is %_hist

Is there a way to improve performance?

```
foreach my $file (@files){
    iLog ("Checking $file");

        $| = 1;  #flush io
        return error("File $file doesn't exist") if not -e $file;

        my @records = readCSVFile($file);   #reads csv file to 2d array and returns the array
        my @formatted_recs;                

        foreach $rec ( @records ){

            my ($time,$c,$user_dst,$client,$ip_src,$first_seen,$last_seen,$first_seen_time,$last_seen_time,$device_ip,$country,$org,$user_agent) = @$rec;



            my @newrec = ($time,$c,$client,$first_seen,$last_seen,$ip_src,$user_agent,$device_ip,$country,$org);

            next if $time =~ /time/i;       #Ignore first record
            push(@formatted_recs, \@newrec);
        }

        baselineHistRecords(@formatted_recs);
}

sub readCSVFile{
my $file = shift;


my @data;
open my $fh, '<', $file or return error("Could not open $file: $!");

my $line = <$fh>;           #Read headerline
my $sep_char = ',';
$sep_char = ';' if $line =~ /;"/;
$sep_char = '|' if $line =~ /\|/;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => "$sep_char" });
push (@data, split(/$sep_char/, $line) );
while( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) { 
    push @data, $row;
}
close $fh;
return @data;
}


sub baselineHistRecords{
my @recs = @_;

undef $_ for ($time,$c,$client,$first_seen,$last_seen,$ip_src,$user_agent,$device_ip,$country,$org) ;
undef $_ for (%device_count, %ua_count,  %location_count, %org_count );
my ($time,$c,$client,$first_seen,$last_seen,$ip_src,$user_agent,$device_ip,$country,$org) ;

my %loc = {}; my %loc2rec = {};
my %device_count = {}; my %ua_count = {}; my %location_count = {}; my %sorg_count = {};
my $hits=0;
my @suspicious_hits = ();


foreach $rec (@recs){
    my $devtag=''; my $os = ''; 

    my @row = @{$rec};
    ($time,$c,$client,$first_seen,$last_seen,$ip_src,$ua,$device_ip,$country,$org) = @row;
    veryverbose("\n$time,$c,$client,$first_seen,$last_seen,$ip_src,$user_agent,$device_ip,$country,$org");

    next if not is_ipv4($ip_src);

    ###### 1. Enrich IP
    my $org = getOrgForIP($ip_src);
    my ($country_code,$region,$city) = getGeoForIP($ip_src);
    my $isp = getISPForIP($ip_src);
    my $loc = join(" > ",($country_code, $region));
    my $city = join(" > ",($country_code, $region, $city));
    my $cidr = $ip_src; $cidr =~ s/\d+\.\d+$/0\.0\/16/; #Removing last octet
#   my $packetmail = getPacketmailRep($ip_src);
#   push (@suspicious_hits, "$time $c $client $ip_src $ua / $packetmail") if $packetmail !~ /NOTFOUND/;

    ##### 2. SANITIZE


    $ua = cannonize($ua);

    $devtag = $& if $ua =~ /\([^\)]+\)/; 
    @tokens = split(/;/, $devtag);
    $os = $tokens[0];
    $os =~ s/\+/ /g;$os =~ s/\(//g;$os =~ s/\)//g;
    $os = 'Android' if $os !~ /Android/i and $devtag =~ /Android/i;
    $os = "Windows NT" if $os =~ /compatible/i or $os =~ /Windows NT/i;


    $_hist{$client}{"isp"}{$isp}{c} += 1;
    $_hist{$client}{"os"}{$os}{c} += 1;
    $_hist{$client}{"ua"}{$ua}{c} += 1 if not is_empty ($ua); 
    $_hist{$client}{"ua"}{c} += 1 if not is_empty ($ua);        #An exception marked since all logs doesn't have UA values
    $_hist{$client}{"loc"}{$loc}{c} += 1; 
    $_hist{$client}{"org"}{$org}{c} += 1;
    $_hist{$client}{"cidr"}{$cidr}{c} += 1;
    $_hist{$client}{"city"}{$city}{c} += 1;
    $_hist{$client}{"c"} += 1;

    $hits = $hits + 1;

    print "." if $hits%100==0;
    debug( "\n$ip_src : $os $loc $isp $org $ua: ".$_hist{$client}{"os"}{$os}{c} );
}

print "\nHITS: $hits";
return if ($hits==0);       #return if empty

printf("\n######(( BASELINE for $client  (".$_hist{$client}{c} ." records) ))#######################\n");   
foreach my $item  (qw/os org isp loc ua cidr/){


    debug( sprintf ("\n\n--(( %s: %s ))-------------------------------- ",$client,uc($item)) );

    ## COMPUTE Usage Percent
    my @item_values = sort { $_hist{$client}{$item}{$b}{c} <=> $_hist{$client}{$item}{$a}{c} } keys %{ $_hist{$client}{$item} };

    my @cvalues = ();
    foreach my $key ( @item_values ){   

        my $count = $_hist{$client}{$item}{$key}{c};
        my $total = $_hist{$client}{c};

        $total = $_hist{$client}{"ua"}{c} if $item =~ /^ua|os$/i and $_hist{$client}{"ua"}{c};      #Over for User_agent and OS determination as all logs doesn't have them


        my $pc = ceil(( $count / $total ) * 100) ;


        debug ("Ignoring empty value") if is_empty($key); # Ignoring Empty values 
        next if is_empty($key);

        $_hist{$client}{$item}{$key}{p} = $pc ;

        push (@cvalues, $pc);
        #printf("\n%3d \% : %s",$pc,$key) if $pc>0;
    }

    ## COMPUTE Cluster Centers
    my @clustercenters =  getClusterCenters(3,@cvalues);
    my ($low, $medium, $high) = @clustercenters;
    $_hist{$client}{$item}{low} = $low;
    $_hist{$client}{$item}{medium} = $medium;
    $_hist{$client}{$item}{high} = $high;

    my %tags = ( $low => "rare", 
                 $medium => "normal", 
                 $high =>"most common",
                 );
    debug ("\n(Cluster Centers) : $low \t$medium \t $high\n");
    foreach my $key ( @item_values ){   
        next if is_empty($key);             
        my $pc = $_hist{$client}{$item}{$key}{p};                   
        $_hist{$client}{$item}{$key}{tag} = $tags{ closest($pc, @clustercenters) };

        debug( sprintf("\n%3d \% : %s : %s",$pc, $_hist{$client}{$item}{$key}{tag} ,  $key) );
    }
}

printf("\n\n###################################\n");

saveHistBaselines();
```

}

Thanks,
Uma

Comment: Please show the code for `flushIO`, `readCSVFile`, and `baselineHistRecords`. Why are you using `$value` in the loop when the control variable is `$file`?

Comment: What is the total files size?

Comment: Sounds like you exceed your memory capacity and start paging (and then thrashing).  Tell us your total memory capacity, OS, whether it's a 32-bit or 64-bit OS and Perl distribution, and total file size.

Comment: I think I am familiar with this situation. I don't know what you want to accomplish having the 2000 csv in memory, but it _might_ not be doable that way due to the hardware limitations on your system. You should try to assess if you actually need everything in memory... most of the times you don't. Two possible alternatives are to process  the data in batches or to store the files in a database and query the data you need afterwards.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish? We're going to need more detail as to what you're doing that loads 'everything' into memory.

Comment: updated remaining functions and machine configuration and file details

Comment: There's tons of copying stuff around in the code that can be replaced with references or removed altogether. This will make memory footprint smaller and allow to read more data before hitting limits.

Answer (score 1):

This is more question for code review.

1. There's a ton of completely useless copying around in the code. E.g.: why the hell you copy data from  my `@$rec` to `@newrec`? `$rec` to `@row`? Why do you return plain list of lines from `readCSVFile` instead of reference?
2. You don't really need to read entire file in memory and then process it - you can process data line by line and throw it away immideately after you done with it.

Comment: `foreach my $file (@files){ 
       

        my @records = readCSVFile($file); 
           
 baselineHistRecords(@records);`


The above code doesn't work

Comment: The code should also work with data that was pulled from database.
 
     so when i pull data from db, i store it in 2D array and pass it on to the function to baseline it.

Comment: @user6554324, why? Get one row from DB, process it, throw it away immideately, repeat.

Comment: right now i guess, i am building the array in memory and expecting the array to be thrown away after building it.
However i think perl is not doing that way.